# Calculate Excel range when user select row numbers and column numbers

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010, interop

I have a method in c# Form Application to return data from excel when given a Range.

```
...
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet aWs = aWb.Worksheets[sheetName] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;

            Range headers = aWs.get_Range(range1, range2);

            object[,] values = headers.get_Value(hmissing) as object[,];
...
```

Here `range1` and `range2` is cell values. Ex: A1 , B7

I want to calculate this `range1` and `range2` when user select row numbers and column numbers.

```
If user select  Rows ={All} and columns = {A,B,C} => result={A1,C265}
If user select  Rows ={1,2,3,4} and columns = {A,B,C} => result={A1,C4}
If user select  Rows ={1,2,4,5} and columns = {A,B,C} => result={A1,C2} {A4,C5}
If user select not matching rows and columns => result={null}
```

How can I do this ? Can we implement a method or Is there any API which provided by Excel to do this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is recalculate formulas Excel has several calculation methods.
 To calculate a specific Range use Range.Calculate or Range.CalculateRowMajorOrder.
 Note that if Excel is in Automatic Calculation mode this should not be required because all formulas are automatically recalculated as required.

Answer (score 0):

Try using LinqToexcel it will help you solve this problem [linqtoexcel](http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/)

hope this helps

Comment: It doesn't have a method that what I wanted. :(